# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor when trying to use jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, input, attributes

May be the error is with respect to my approach with jQuery. I am not sure how to get around this. Hence thought of putting this together to get some help. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have some input elements rendered on to my web page based on some back-end logic, so appearance of questions tend to change. I am trying to 'set' the value of 'type' to 'tel' for those elements having its class defined as 'GTnumeric' and value of 'type' is not 'hidden' (I am not in a position to change any logic in the back-end and hence trying to achieve this on front-end).

The below code using html dom elements works fine but I trying to figure out a way to achieve the same using jQuery:

```
<input class="validated GTnumeric" size="3" type="hidden" value="">
<input class="validated GTnumeric" size="2" type="text" value="">
```

Working code:

```
 var r = $('[class="validated GTnumeric"]');
 for(var ec in eClass){
    if(eClass[ec].getAttribute("type") != 'hidden'){
       eClass[ec].setAttribute("type","tel");
    }
 }
```

NOT Working Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                        
        var inputEls = $(".GTnumeric");
        for(var ec in inputEls){
            if($(inputEls[ec]).attr("type") != 'hidden'){
                $(ec).attr("type","tel");
            }
        }
     });
```

Could you please guide me on this. It will be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: You have an array of jQuery objects, not DOM elements (they're contained within the jQuery elements).  You can use jQuery's `.each()` to parse them.  See here -> **https://api.jquery.com/each/**

Comment: i had this error and changing `Window` to `window` in this code >  `$(window).trigger('resize');`. fixed my problem. it was a typo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a collection of jQuery objects, not DOM elements (they're contained within the jQuery objects), so you can parse them using `.each()`, where `$(this)` is each element within the function.

This is what you're trying to do, with corrected jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
    var inputEls = $(".GTnumeric");
    inputEls.each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("type") != "hidden"){
            $(this).attr("type", "tel");
        }
    });
});
```

However, you can just target the elements in question with the selector and do it this way...

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
    $(".GTnumeric").not("[type=hidden]").attr("type", "tel");
});
```

---

Here's an example...

```js
$(".GTnumeric").not("[type=hidden]").attr("type", "tel");

$(".GTnumeric").each(function() { console.log(this.getAttribute("type")); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GTnumeric" type="hidden"></div>
<div class="GTnumeric" type="hidden"></div>
<div class="GTnumeric" type="something"></div>
<div class="GTnumeric" type="else"></div>
<div class="GTnumeric" type="here"></div>
```

Comment: Wow you r a genius :) yup that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot giving a working model and showing me the shortcut version!! thanks a ton.

Comment: wish I could up vote the answer as well, sorry that I am not yet privileged to do so. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries mate - glad I could help :)